# Is Apple deprecating UIPopover?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

Since iOS 5.1 was released, the default for showing the Master view controller in split views is a slide in type of thing. In order to present a popover it seems like you have to enable it using a UIPopover controller instead. Does this mean that the popover is going to going out of style?

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa!  Deprecation and changes to a couple of internal properties are two different animals here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Apple's API's, *deprecated* means that Apple has specifically stated that something is in the process of going away. It's usually accompanied by advice regarding a new way to accomplish the same thing. So, if Apple ever deprecates UIPopoverController, you'll know it just from reading the documentation.

That said, it's also a good idea to read the release notes for each new version of iOS that comes along. In the [iOS 5.1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_1/_index.html) you'll find a note that explains what you're seeing:

> In 5.1 the UISplitViewController class adopts the sliding presentation
>   style when presenting the left view (previously only seen in Mail).
>   This style is used when presentation is initiated either by the
>   existing bar button item provided by the delegate methods or by a
>   swipe gesture within the right view. No additional API adoption is
>   required to obtain this behavior, and all existing API, including that
>   of the UIPopoverController instance provided by the delegate, will
>   continue to work as before.

Comment: Okay so maybe depreciate is the wrong word for me to use. Since this is now the default behavior, is it recommended that we stop usin popovers to show the master VC in favor of this new slide in gesture?

Comment: I haven't seen such a recommendation. Popover views still seem useful -- it's just that UISplitViewController has changed its behavior somewhat.